# d3.js Node Position in Force Directed Graph following Search

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

Objective: center a node in the viewing area following search

I created a force directed graph that enables a user to search for a node by name. When a node is searched, the selected node remains visible while all other nodes temporarily reduce opacity to highlight the searched node. Now, I would also like to center the searched node in the viewing area. I have attempted numerous methods, but have been unsuccessful in translating the entire graph including node labels. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

jsfiddle (note: autocomplete search works perfectly when run from my script but seems to fail in jsfiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/dereksmith5822/73j63nn0/

```
<script>

var width = 900,
    height = 590;

var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1,5]).on("zoom", redraw)).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
        .append('g');

//INPUT DATA
var links = [
    {source: 'N1', target: 'N2'},
    {source: 'N1', target: 'N3'},
    {source: 'N2', target: 'N3'},
    {source: 'N3', target: 'N4'},
];

var nodes = [ 
    {id: 'N1', name: 'A'},
    {id: 'N2', name: 'B'},
    {id: 'N3', name: 'C'},
    {id: 'N4', name: 'D'},
];

//CONNECTIONS
var hash_lookup = [];
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  hash_lookup[d.id] = d;
});
links.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.source = hash_lookup[d.source];
  d.target = hash_lookup[d.target];
});

//FORCE LAYOUT
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .on('tick', tick)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .gravity(.15)
    .friction(.8)
    .linkStrength(1)
    .charge(-425)
    .chargeDistance(600)
    .start();

//LINKS
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');

//NODES
var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', width * 0.01)

//LABELS
var text_center = false;
var nominal_text_size = 12;
var max_text_size = 22;
var nominal_base_node_size = 8;
var max_base_node_size = 36;    
var size = d3.scale.pow().exponent(1)
  .domain([1,100])
  .range([8,24]);

var text = svg.selectAll(".text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("font-size", nominal_text_size + "px")

    if (text_center)
     text.text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");

    else 
    text.attr("dx", function(d) {return (size(d.size)|| nominal_base_node_size);})
    .text(function(d) { return '\u2002'+d.name; });

//ZOOM AND PAN
function redraw() {
    svg.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
        + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

var drag = force.drag()
      .on("dragstart", function(d) {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      });

//NODES IN SPACE
function tick(e) {

    text.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(force.drag);

    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

};

//AUTOCOMPLETE SEARCH
var optArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length - 1; i++) {
    optArray.push(nodes[i].name);
}
optArray = optArray.sort();

$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: optArray
    });
});

function searchNode() {
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById('search').value;
    if (selectedVal == 'none') {}
    else {
        var selected = node.filter(function (d, i) {
            return d.name != selectedVal;
        });
         var selectedText = text.filter(function (d, i) {
            return d.name != selectedVal;
        });
        selected.style("opacity", "0");
        selectedText.style("opacity", "0");
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            link.style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".node, .link, .text").transition()
            .duration(3000)
            .style("opacity", '1');
    }
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea how you can do it:

Save your `zoom` behaviour:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1,5]).on("zoom", redraw);
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .append('g');
```

In `searchNode` function:

```
var selectedNode = node
    .filter(function (d, i) { return d.name == selectedVal; })
    .datum();
var desiredPosition = { x: 100, y: 100 }; // constants, set to svg center point
zoom.translate([desiredPosition.x - selectedNode.x, desiredPosition.y - selectedNode.y]);
zoom.event(svg);
```

This code does not respect zoom's scale. I think you can just get `zoom.scale()` and multiply selectedNode coordinates by it.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. The code works to position the selected node in the center of the field; however, upon either pan or zoom the graph reverts to the original positions. Modifying ".call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null)" results in the error "Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'apply' of undefined". Do you know the reason for this error? Thanks.

Comment: It works for me without errors in Firefox 48. My fork of your fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/v71d1ha8/

Comment: I'm using chrome. I resolved the error, but if I either pan or zoom following the node being centered the graph reverts to the original position before centering. Have you found a way to enable pan and zoom to be implemented from the new node position? Thanks

Comment: It's strange, I do not encounter this problem. By calling `zoom.translate()` you tell zoom behaviour to use new coordinates. Could you share another fiddle?

Comment: I apologize, I was missing the var scale. It works perfectly! Thanks!